# JObject formatting

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm trying to get the tables into json string (just an example)

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add( "David");

var Result = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
     select new {  name = (string)row["Name"] };
JObject json = JObject.FromObject(new {Result});
return json;
```

I'm getting this:

```
"Table":{"Result":[{"name":"David"}]}
```

But need this:

```
"Result":[{"name":"David"}]
```

Is there are any ways to format the string and get rid of "table"/"result"/etc, combining them in one? (may be not json.net?)

Comment: those both examples aren't valid json.

Comment: well, yes, it's just a part of a whole string {"Data":{"Table":{"Result":[{"name":"David"}]}}}.

Comment: try using `JObject.FromObject(Result)`.

Comment: You are using the same variable name with DataTable. I think you wrote wrong. EDITED

Comment: I cannot reproduce this -- your code generates `{"Result":[{"name":"David"}]}` as desired.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/OGq20T.  Please try to [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. needed to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` instead of `JObject`

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky solution to this problem.
Let's say after what your code your `JObject json` got this value:

> {"Data":{"Table":{"Result":[{"name":"David"}]}}}

All you need to do is just extract desired value from it as `JObject`:

```
JObject newJson = json.GetValue("Data").Value<JObject>().GetValue("Table").Value<JObject>();
```